# Yii1.1 activeForm DateTime

Tags: yii, yii1.x, active-form

i am trying to get a datetimepicker in Yii 1.1.16

until now  i used bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm and did nicely and easy:

```
<?php echo  $form->dateFieldControlGroup($model, 'date'); ?>
```

but now i need a dateTime insteed of only date but there is nothing like dateTimeFieldControlGroup...
https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/TbHtml/activeTextField/php-tbhtml-activetextfield-method-examples.html

I tried

```
<?php echo  $form->dateTimeLocalField($model, 'datetime'); ?>
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#dateTimeLocalField-detail

with dateTimeLocalField i can save values but existing values will not be displaed in the picker....

Answer (score 1):

on this link you can download Yii 1.x widgets for bootstrap...

https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiibooster

The name you looking for is TbDateTimePicker